# Restrict some commands for user/group using sudoers (visudo)

Tags: sudo, account-restrictions

I want to create group and want to allow the group to run all available commands except few commands. Can you please help me configure sudoers for the same.

I checked but only found how to allow some commands. But I want to restrict some commands and allow remaining all.

Thanks

Comment: The problem in allowing “all commands except a few” through sudo is, your users will almost certainly be able to use the allowed commands to create aliases or renamed copies of the forbidden commands... which will then be allowed. So such a restriction will be very weak and easy to bypass.

Comment: You do understand that `sudoers` is considered ONLY if `$USER` prefaces her command with `sudo`, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `!` operator. See the details in the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers).

Note, from the same manpage the following security note:

> Limitations of the '!' operator
>
> It is generally not effective to ''subtract'' commands from ALL using
> the '!' operator. A user can trivially circumvent this by copying the
> desired command to a different name and then executing that.